# EJB : Two stateless objects use two different transaction

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, eclipselink, jta

I would like to ask question regarding EJB. I am using eclipselink of JPA.

There is two stateless objects in a stateless object in my code.

Is that possible this two stateless object use two different transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  You may find it useful to read about the [transaction attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html).

If the called method in your first class (say `StatelessFirst`) has a transaction type `REQUIRED` (the default) or `REQUIRES_NEW`, when it is called it will initiate a new transaction.  If this then calls a method in your second class (say `StatelessSecond`) with transaction type `REQUIRES_NEW`, the first transaction is suspended and a second transaction is initiated while the second method executes.  When the method in `StatelessSecond` completes, the second transaction commits, the first transaction is reinstated, and control is passed back to `StatelessFirst`.

To make the first transaction commit before `StatelessSecond` is called, you can use [bean-managed transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html).  This gives you full control over the transaction management, so in `StatelessFirst` you can begin a transaction, then commit then call `StatelessSecond`.  If you go with this approach, note that you [can't perform nested transactions](http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/bean-managed-transactions-ejb-3/) in BMT.

One other option which allows you to stay within CMT would be to pull the transactional behaviour out of `StatelessFirst` into a third EJB, with `REQUIRES_NEW`.  Then the pattern is:

- Client calls `StatelessFirst`, which initiates transaction A
- `StatelessFirst` calls `NewBean`, which initiates transaction B, and performs some work
- `NewBean` commits transaction B and returns
- `StatelessFirst` calls `StatelessSecond`, which initiates transaction C, and performs its work
- `StatelessSecond` commits transaction C and returns
- `StatelessFirst` completes, and commits transaction A (which doesn't have any changes anyway)

Comment: Okay, I actually has declared both java method require_new 1 day ago. However. what I hope is the statelessfirst should commit before exectuting statelesssecond. Not like what was written by you ---> the first transaction is suspended and a second transaction is initiated while the second method executes.

Comment: Ah, ok, then you'll be needing bean-managed transactions.  I'll edit this in to my answer.